# how to increment and decrement state value in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to increment and decrement state value in react using `react-redux`.I add actions , container ,reducer .But I don't know how to subscribe the `increment` and `decrement` action here is my code

I want to increment and decrement the value when user click on buttons

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVjMXv?editors=1010

```
   const abc= (state=0,action) => {
  console.log(action.type)
  switch(action.type){
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state +1
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state -1
      Default :
      return state;
  }
}
const {createStore,bindActionCreators} =Redux;
const {Provider,connect} =ReactRedux;

const store = createStore(abc);


class First extends React.Component {
  constructor (){
    super();
    this.state ={
    digit :0  
    }
  }
  inc (){
    console.log('ince')
  }

  dec (){
    console.log('dec')
  }
  render(){
    return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.inc.bind(this)}>INCREMENT</button>
        <p>{this.state.digit}</p>
        <button onClick={this.dec.bind(this)}>DECREMENT</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
} 

const actions = {
    increment: () => {
        return {
            type: 'INCREMENT',
        }
    },
     decrement: () => {
        return {
            type: 'DECREMENT',
        }
    }
};

const AppContainer = connect(
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            digit: state
        };
    },
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
    }
)(First);
ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
    <First/>
  </Provider>
  ,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a lot of changes

**First:** Since you are connecting your First component to state and actions as AppContainer you need to render it in DOM

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer/>
  </Provider>
  ,document.getElementById('root'))
```

**Second**: you are dispatching actions `INC` and `DEC` and you are handling `INCREMENT`, `DECREMENT` in reducer

**Third**: You should render the state you get from redux and not the component state like

```
{this.props.digit}
```

**Fourth**:

call the action via the props like `this.props.increment()`, `this.props.decrement()`

**Complete Code**

```
const abc= (state=0,action) => {
  console.log('in redux', action.type)
  switch(action.type){
    case 'INC':

      return state +1
    case 'DEC':
      return state -1
      default :
      return state;
  }
}
const {createStore,bindActionCreators} =Redux;
const {Provider,connect} =ReactRedux;

const store = createStore(abc);


class First extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
    digit :0  
    }
  }
  inc (){
    console.log('ince', this.props)
    this.props.increment();
  }

  dec (){
    console.log('dec')
    this.props.decrement();
  }
  render(){
    return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.inc.bind(this)}>INCREMENT</button>
        <p>{this.props.digit}</p>
        <button onClick={this.dec.bind(this)}>DECREMENT</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
} 

const actions = {
    increment: () => {
        return {
            type: 'INC',
        }
    },
     decrement: () => {
        return {
            type: 'DEC',
        }
    }
};

const AppContainer = connect(
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            digit: state
        };
    },
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch);
    }
)(First);
ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer/>
  </Provider>
  ,document.getElementById('root'))
```

**[Here is a working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoVKeg?editors=1011)**

Comment: why you are rendering 'containers' ...so if I have two components `(First, Second ) `each have  individual containers (`AppContainer1` ,`AppContainer2`) ..so will i add  containers in render method ?? or only component ?

Comment: The thing is since your are using connect to attach mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps and giving it a name AppContainer before exporting it you need to use AppContainer in ReactDOM.render() because if you dont the First will not be able to access the props or else you can directly do export default connect(...)(First) in your code and not in codepen

Answer (score 0):

Very simple code INC and DEC: props and state

Complete Code:

```
class APP extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props)
      this.state ={
      digit: 0
     }
      this.onIncrement = this.onIncrement.bind(this);
      this.onDecrement = this.onDecrement.bind(this);
    }
    onIncrement()
    {
      this.setState({
        digit: this.state.digit + 1
        )}
    }
    onDecrement()
    {
      this.setState({
        digit: this.state.digit - 1
      )}
    }
    render()
    {
     return(<p>{this.state.digit}</p>
     <button type="button" onClick={this.onIncrement}> + </button>
     <button type="button" onClick={this.onDecrement}> - </button>)
    }
}
```

export default APP;